# Dixon's Theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability

I am going through a sketch of the proof of Dixon's Theorem (the probability that two randomly chosen elements of A_n generate A_n -> 1 as n -> infinity) due to M. Liebeck and its underlying idea is that if two even permutations fail to generate A_n, then they must both be contained in some maximal subgroup of A_n.

I can't see why this is the case?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two elements of ${\rm A}_n$ which do not lie both in any maximal subgroup of
${\rm A}_n$, then they in particular do not lie both in *any* proper subgroup of ${\rm A}_n$.
This in turn means that the only subgroup of ${\rm A}_n$ which contains your elements is
${\rm A}_n$ itself. Hence your two elements *generate* ${\rm A}_n$.